Does the root mean square (RMS) value of the impulse response function (IRF) mean for something？
Considering a single-input, multiple-output linear system, I have the impulse response function between the input point and each output point. If I calculate the RMS of each impulse response function, what does this value represent? Can it be explained that, under the same white noise input, a larger RMS of the impulse response function corresponds to a larger actual response RMS?
I searched online and found that hardly anyone calculates the RMS of the impulse response. Are there any metrics used in practice to evaluate an IRF? Or, in other words, what indicators from the IRF can I use to evaluate the response characteristics of different output points to the same input point?

@V.V.T  it's a vibration test system. I want to place the sensor in a location with the highest possible signal-to-noise ratio. So I want to know if it is possible to evaluate directly by calculating the RMS of the impulse response function or some other indicators. Because if we assume that the noise is only related to the sensor itself, the larger the response, the higher the signal-to-noise ratio.

@V.V.T The evaluation metrics I’ve encountered most often are time delay, response amplitude, duration, and similar indicators. I have rarely seen metrics that process the entire impulse response vector, like calculating the RMS.

I feel that the response peak of the impulse response is related to the time interval. It is possible that the peak of a particular impulse response might not be captured because it happens to be missed due to the time interval. Therefore, in my understanding, this metric may not hold much significance.


If I calculate the RMS of each impulse response function, what does this value represent?

The square root of the power that a unit-power impulse has at the output. In other words, this factor describes the relationship between in- and output power.

Can it be explained that, under the same white noise input, a larger RMS of the impulse response function corresponds to a larger actual response RMS?

Yes, trivially. That's literally what the PSD of a channel is.

I searched online and found that hardly anyone calculates the RMS of the impulse response

You might want to look into your MIMO introductory literature instead of online! This factor is very important for determining scaling in diversity schemes. You might want to read up on equal gain combining and maximum rate combining.
